# I will not be able to log back into Windows 10 when I log out.

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, passwords, user-accounts

I changed the password on my Windows 10 account earlier today but can't for the life of me remember what I changed it to. Therefore, when I log out or turn the computer off, I will not be able to log back in to my account.

The computer is still on, and I am still logged into the account in question. I currently have access. What can I do from here to reset the password?

Thanks gents! Sorry to be so stupid, I am kicking myself

Answer (score 1):

If your user is a local user (not a Microsoft account like user@hotmail.com), you can do this:

1. Create a new user **with admin privileges**.
2. Log off.
3. Log in with the new user and change other user's password.

If it is a Microsoft account, try to login to that Microsoft service and change the password or try "I don't remember my password" and change it **before** you log off.

Answer (score 0):

#### What can I do from here to reset the password?

If you are still logged on you can use `net user` from a `cmd` shell to change the password.

**Solution 1 (with prompts)**:

```
net user user_name *
```

Now enter a new password and retype the password to confirm the password.

**Solution 2 (no prompts)**:

```
net user user_name new_password
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.

Comment: That's a good one. but I think it wont work with a Microsoft account, because it's not a "local user". In example, you can't use `net user` with an Active Directory user... even if your are logged in with it.

Comment: @Santeador Really? `/domain`   : Performs the operation on the domain controller in the computer's primary domain.

Comment: My apologizes, you're right. Can you test it with a Microsoft account? I don't have a W10 nearby...

Comment: I don't have Windows 10 or AD to test it either :/

Comment: Let me see if I can borrow one... now I am intrigued if it will work with a Microsoft account.

Comment: Tested.

First, when you add a new user using Microsoft account, W10 adds a local user using first 5 characters of Microsoft user ID. You can see it at the users MMC (lusrmgr.msc).

But if you try `net user LocalID password` it will tell you this: "System error 8646 has occurred.
The system is not authoritative for the specified account and therefore cannot complete the operation. Please retry the operation using the provider associated with this account. If this is an online provider please use the provider's online site."

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are still logged in this is easy.

While at the desktop do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on your keyboard

this will bring up a menu, select Change Password. You can change it as many times as you want if you do not log out, restart or shutdown.

[image]
[image]